# Why is my script for the powerbutton not working under 14.04 LTS an 16.04 LTS any longer?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 16.04, scripts

I have an little homeserver based on ubuntu 16.04 LTS without a graphical userinterface. He was set up with 10.04 LTS an always upgraded.
In version 13 I changed the behaviour of the power button via script to realise that shutdown when powerbutton is pressed once and suspend when powerbutton is pressed twice within two seconds is initiated. The script works fine until the upgrade to version 14.04. Until this time the script only works if I start it via commandline. If it runs via powerbutton-event it always beeps twice and the server goes sleeping. It looks like the if-construction isn't working!? I had a little success when I put doubblebrackets `if [[ -e $LOCKFILE ]]` around the teststatement. The if-construct worked but deleting the lockfile doesn’t work.

/etc/acpi/powerbutton.sh (bind to the powerbutton-event):

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh

[ -r /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs ] && . /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs
# call the subscript as single threat
/etc/acpi/suspend_or_shutdown.sh &
```

/etc/acpi/suspend_or_shutdown.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/acpi/suspend_or_shutdown.sh

[ -r /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs ] && . /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs

# 1x pressed = halt (within 2s)
# 2x pressed = suspend to disk

#Skip if we just in the middle of resuming
test -f /var/lock/acpisleep && exit 0

#file for decision
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/suspend_or_shutdown.lock

#acustic feedback 
beep -l 50 -D 500

#exists /run/lock/suspend_or_shutdown.lock ?
if [ -e $LOCKFILE ]
then
    #yes -> suspend (power button pressend second time)
    #del lockfile
    rm $LOCKFILE
    # 2x beep for feedback
    beep -r 2 -d 100
    # SLEEP to S3
#   pm-suspend
### OR ###
    acpitool --suspend
else
    #no -> create lockfile with PID
    echo "$$" > $LOCKFILE
    #wait 2s
    sleep 2
    #if pressed 2x, lockfile is deleted
    if [ -e $LOCKFILE ]
    then
        #delete lockfile
        rm $LOCKFILE
        # 1x beep
        beep
        # shutdown server
        shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
    else
        exit 0
    fi
fi
```

I had no idea why the script isn't working (except via commandline). If anyone had an idea, please let me know...
Thank you much :-)

Schiki